# How to fix system freezing when using a Dedicated GPU (INTEL + AMD)?

Tags: dual-boot, intel-graphics, radeon, amdgpu, hybrid-graphics

So, I decided to make a dual boot (Windows + Ubuntu). When I used my **Intel HD Graphics 520** card everything was fine. But when I want to play some games using Proton or Lutris with my dedicated GPU: **AMD Radeon R5 M330** - oh man, everything worked really bad. Well, in most cases it didn't work at all.

I used **'DRI_PRIME = 1'**, **'Launch using Dedicated Graphics Card' option** etc.

When I launched simple applications like Steam, it worked for a while but after that - freeze.
When I ran complicated games, they didn't run at all (black screen) or they generated a single frame and kept freezing:

[image: screenshot]

When I tried to turn off this apps, there are two scenarios:

1. **My system freezes** and I have to turn off the computer by holding on/off button on the keyboard
2. **They don't turn off anyway** (even if I use "Kill process" option)

I know about **amdgpu** driver, so I **blacklisted radeon** and it seems to be using amdgpu but it still doesn't work - at least, it shows name of the device properly (with radeon driver sometimes it shows my card as 'llvmpipe', lol). Maybe I did that wrong...how can I check it btw.?

I decided to change my OS from Ubuntu to Pop! OS (because I heard it is more optimized for games) but my dGPU seems to work exactly the same as on clean Ubuntu so I wrote about my problem on this forum. If it is a problem, please write on which website can I ask and close this topic - thanks.

Why is my AMD Radeon R5 M330 not working properly on Linux (on Windows is everything okay)? Can I fix it somehow? I will be grateful for any help.